# a series from continued fraction expansion of an irrational number

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

if $\theta $ is a irrational number, it has a continued fraction expansion
$$[a_{0}, \dots a_{n}, \dots ] =
a_{0}+\frac{1}{a_{1}+\frac{1}{\dots}}
$$
the associated rational approximations is $p_{n}/q_{n}= [a_{0}, \dots a_{n} ] $ 
I want to show that $\sum {\frac{1}{q_{n} }} $is finite
from the recursion formular I obtain that 
$$p_{n}q_{n-1}-p_{n-1}q_{n}=(-1)^{n-1}$$ 
it follows that $p_{n}/q_{n}$ is an alternating series, and I have no clue what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

From the [recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems)
$$
 p_n = a_n p_{n-1} + p_{n-2} \\
 q_n = a_n q_{n-1} + q_{n-2}
$$
and the fact that all $a_n \ne 0$ for an irrational number it follows that
in particular
$$
  q_n \ge  q_{n-1} + q_{n-2}
$$
and therefore $q_n \ge F_n$ ($n$-th Fibonacci number). The conclusion follows
because $\sum \frac{1}{F_n}$ [is convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_Fibonacci_constant).